# Xamarin.Forms iOS shows "Master" and "Detail" instead of just back icon or menu icon

Tags: xamarin.forms

on Android, my app shows a little arrow in the navigation bar up top that, once clicked on, brings you back one screen. But iOS, ofc is special, shows the word "DETAL" and "MASTER".

The do the same (open the menu, go back) but its wierd.

THis is how I open the page:

```
    button_test.Clicked += delegate
    {


        Application.Current.MainPage = new Screen_MainMenu();
    };
```

Can someone tell me, what is going on and how to just make it show the arrow and not the words?

Answer (score 1):

Find the code where you set the icon on `Page.IconImageSource` ,  you have to ensure the image(back icon) already exists under the resource folder or image assets in iOS project .